# How to arrange picture like this

Tags: html, css, laravel

I just want to arrange post pictures randomly that comes from database to be arrange like below demo picture please help?

[image: demo]

```
  <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="footer_widget_title">
                    <h3><a href="category.html" target="_self">Tech Photos</a></h3>
                </div>
                @foreach($shareData['categories'] as $category) 
        @foreach($category['subcategory'] as $subcategory)
        @foreach($subcategory->posts as $key=>$item) 
                   <div class="category_article_wrapper">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom: 2%">
                <div class="media">
                    <div class="media-left">
                        <a href="{{ url('/details') }}/{{ $item->slug }}"><img class="media-object" src="{{ asset('post') }}/{{ $item->thumb_image }}"
                                         alt="{{ $item->title }}"></a>
                    </div></div> </div> </div> </div> @endforeach 

             @endforeach @endforeach 


            </div>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific, because it's not clear what aspect of this you need help with. Is it in the Eloquent query? The CSS? Do you want to use Bootstrap or do it vanilla? Are you struggling to iterate through the collection in the Blade file (addressed in Digvijay's post)?

Comment: This is in eloquent query , and it's clear what i want to do because i didn't say how to get posts or data i have just asked about how to arrange posts

Comment: CSS Grid of images, with `object-fit: cover` set on the images?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say `$data` variable consist of all the images. We can use [chunk()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-chunk) of 3 and loop through it.

In your blade file

```
@foreach($data->chunk(3) as $pictures)
   <tr class="row">  // will create a new row after each loop of 3
        @foreach($pictures as $picture)
            <td class="col-md-4"> <img src="{{ $picture->src }}"/> </td>
        @endforeach
   </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: This is a fantastic tip - I'd never thought to use chunk like that in Blade.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it is what you need

```
@foreach($shareData['posts'] as $item)

    <div style="display: inline-grid; width: 100px; margin: auto; grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;  "> 

<a href="{{ url('/details') }}/{{ $item->slug }}" ><img class="img-responsive"
                     src="{{ asset('post') }}/{{ $item->thumb_image }} " alt="{{ $item->title }}">
                    </a>

    </div> @endforeach
```